# PyXB and python frameworks

Tags: xml, django, binding, schema, pyramid

I used [PyXB](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/) to generate Python modules out of a java/spring platform that exposes its classes schemas in XSD format via a RESTfull API.

I am now able to parse the XML data that the same platform serves, using those PyXB binding classes/modules.

My question is:

- How can I leverage those classes, in frameworks like Django or
  pyramid, to build dynamic model forms, tables, etc, as I would do
  using models coming from models.py django ORM, or via [colander](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/)/[deform](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/deform/en/latest/)
  or [pyramid-simpleform](http://packages.python.org/pyramid_simpleform/)?
- Has anybody used PyXB classes in any of those
  frameworks yet?

Comment: I think I am finally moving to generateDS (http://packages.python.org/generateDS) which generates way cleaner code from my schemas.
But the question about using it after by dynamically generate a Colander schema out of that generateDS/PyXB generated class remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it would be to create a mapping from PyXB bindings to form library. For example, it shouldn't be too hard to write some code that generate a colander schema from a PyXB class. Once you have the schema, all you need is a way to serialize and deserialize your objects in the same format (which quite simple : only values in lists and dicts), and you'll be able to create forms from PyXB objects and save them back.

This has already been done with colander and sqlalchemy, and [the code for ColanderAlchemy](https://github.com/stefanofontanelli/ColanderAlchemy) may give you some inspiration on how to do it.

Bonus points if you put it on pypi :)

Comment: I actually discovered ColanderAlchemy 2 days ago and I also had in mind to look into the code to get inspiration.
Thanks a lot.